# Only relayout children and not all the tree

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to recreate `ListView` (and `AbsListView`) logic, with view recycling.
I need this but we can say it's only for understand Android logic.

Suppose my children items are the same (same layout), using fixed height `RelativeLayout`.

During scrolling, I'm reusing ghost children view and set properties for current item.
It's working fine, since I'm using `View.offsetTopAndBottom()` and `invalidate()` instead of requesting layout during scroll for optimization.

My problem is updating the children (`RelativeLayout`).

Depends of item, I want to hide or show `ImageView` on this item. For that, I'm just using `iconImage.setVisibility( GONE )` and `iconImage.setVisibility( VISIBLE )`.

Since I'm blocking `requestLayout`, it seems to be `setVisibility()` does not work properly.

If I use `requestLayout`, all the tree will measure and layout itself, and it's not a good way for a scrolling user experience.

Is there a way for only request layout on recycle child item ?

Answer (score -2):

You need to notify your listView with changed of view so call `notifyDataSetChanged();` from Uithread like this :

```
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = ((ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter());
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```