# Performance: How to prevent requestLayout() from laying out entire hierarchy

Tags: android, performance, layout

I have a pretty complex android-application. Already flattened view-hierarchies as far as possible, but I still have lags in the application. For example there is a menu with entries that collapse/expand by having their height set by a `ValueAnimator`. Typically the animation runs with a bit of a lag the first time, and smooth after this first pass.

I noticed that when i call "requestLayout()" on the Menu-Item, Android seems to do a layout-pass and multiple measure-passes through the entire hierarchy.

- Since i know that although the Menu-Item(View) changes height, the Menu(View) itself doesn't, is there some way to tell this to the application?
- Can i somehow perform this first pass that seems to lag myself so that it occurs after application start-up and not at the first touch-input?

Here's a sketch of the animation I'm doing:

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. For me it's even more annoying, I have a complex list with custom view icons. All list is redrawn when a small text window is updates (every 1 sex) below it. That introduces a short lag.

Comment: @ArtursVancans hey, arturs, I ran into this too.It is will be great thanks if you could share how you get rid off this.

Comment: Check out React-Native or libraries like anko.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure why a layout is being triggered in your animation but I am going to answer your question abstractly.

If you are calling requestLayout (either directly or indirectly) in your animation you are doing it WRONG.

requestLayout, for correctness and safety, does a full view traversal on the view hierarchy b/c conceptually changing bounding box of a node in the view hierarchy can result in change in the bounds of any other node. Not always the case but in general it could, thats why requestLayout is a full traversal.

All of this is just another way of saying requestLayout will eat away time from your 16.6 ms frame time slot and make your animation choppy. This is especially bad for deep and complex hierarchies with many RelativeLayouts which internally does two passes per level (thus potentially causing exponential passes on a subtree)

Now, if you want to animate change in dimension use setScale in a hardware layer. And at the end of the animation merrily call requestlayout and also destroy the layer (to free up memory).

Because its a layer, repeatedly calling setScale in your animation results in change of the texture on the GPU and as a result totally bypass the traversal mechanism of the view hierarchy. This should make it buttery smooth.

Comment: A layout is being triggered because I'm setting the height of a RelativeLayout. I want it to collapse from full-height to a showing only the uppermost view it contains.

Comment: The animation runs smooth now, I just have this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089548/android-programmatically-invoke-ndrawdisplaylist 
(it lags the first time it runs, after that it runs smooth everytime)

Comment: Another question to you: I got how the layout process works by now, but is there really no way to tell android that parts of a layout haven't changed, so that it doesn't need to remeasure them at least? The measuring part is the most expensive in my application.

Comment: @FabianZeindl like i said use setScale during animation and at the end of your animation change your dimension and call requestLayout. This way your actual change of dimensions and hence layout happens at the end of animation not during it but you still get the illusion of dimension changing (via setScale)

Comment: @FabianZeindl i'm not sure i understand - if part of your layout hasn't change then you shouldn't be calling requestLayout to begin with, right? A layout pass will always end up doing measurement - no way around that.

Comment: I've added a sketch of the animation I'm doing. I have this RelativeLayout, which I collapse, so it only shows the first line of text. I animate the LayoutParams.height from the whole height to just the height of the text-line on top.

Comment: This layout DOES change, but it's only a fraction of the whole layout of my application. In this case I know that even if this box changes height, the surrounding box which contains it doesn't change. Neither do the other elements.

I thought about writing a Layout that caches measurements, until I tell it to forget the height of this box only during the animation. So measurement will run faster. It pretty complicated though to stay compatible with existing android views and layouts.

Comment: The picture helps a lot. Changing LayoutParams will cause requestLayout so doing it repeatedly in animation is bad. How about this solution - If the box collapses to the same height you put everything except the first line in a Framelayout and change its visibility to invisible/gone (animate it). If you have LayoutTransition setup for outer box, the container will automatically animate the dimensions for you.

Comment: about caching measurements for the duration of the animation, that is a fine optimization. setMeasure like onLayout is recursive. You can always avoid recursing down the subtree (via measureChildren) and just call setMeasureDimensions directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks like mine: [Only relayout children and not all the tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121742/only-relayout-children-and-not-all-the-tree)

First, you can try to avoid complex view hierarchy for your view. If possible, explode views on views that doesn't depend on another one.

When an animation is performed, avoid any layout request. Start your animation with a delay if a layout request is pending.

Use hardware layers for animation if possible (maybe Android use it by default with `ValueAnimator`)

Comment: I made my view-hierarchy as flat as possible, without having to merge ridiculous amounts of code. Hardware-acceleration is there, though it took a lot of trial on error to find out on which layers to enable or disable it to get expected results.

Comment: How do I detect if a layout-request is pending?

Comment: As I know, you can't. System can itself request layout. Don't call addView(), removeView() or something like that just before animating. If you can't avoid that, use a post() or handler to start animation with 100ms delay for example, it can help.

Comment: If your UI is too deep or complex, try to draw custom view instead of using some layout and views

Comment: Yeah, but that makes my code really bloated. And I hate that I'd have to throw away so much from Android and replace it with my own code.