# Android: programmatically invoke nDrawDisplayList

Tags: android, performance

My, rather complex, application has two or three lags of about 500ms, which TraceView shows to be in `GLES20Canvas.nDrawDisplayList`. These lags only occur once when doing certain steps, after that everythings runs smoothly.

Is there a way to invoke this calls on activity create/resume?

Please don't give me answers in the "draw less"-category. My code/layouts are already tightly optimized and i'm no beginner in writing performant java-applications. I also read pretty much any android-performance-tutorial Google finds.

I have to use large views with dozens of nested `ImageView`s and `TextView`s that are being displayed and animated around, I can't find more ways of reducing complexity further, without making development and code-reusability of this application a nightmare.

Comment: Did you tried to use hardware layer for animated views? Also, are you sure that you're not using large images while drawing (even if they're downscaled programmatically via `scaleType`)? And the last one, I can hardly imagine that all those views did fit on a device screen at once - I assume you're using some sort of scrolling container, is that true?

Comment: And, I assume that you read this article (which should at least partially explain why you having problems with display list): http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html

Comment: They fit on the screen since it's a tablet-app. I don't use a scrolling container. I've read the article of course, it basically states "in android sometimes hw-acceleration works and sometimes it doesn't because of some reasons that apply sometimes'.

Comment: I managed to get my performance by using `TextView`s that share `Paint` objects and various other tricks.

Comment: @FabianZeindl What were the other tricks? Could you post them as an answer to your question?

Comment: Rather not, since it's a different topic. I stopped using reflection/EventBus everywhere. I replaced "rulers" which where views with ````onDraw()```` routines.

Comment: Best just profile your app, never optimize without profiling first!